# Shell script commands

Tags: grass-gis, shell

I have this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
r.mapcalc water = 120
d.rast water
i=1
while [ $i != 100 ]
do
    n=1
    while [ $n != 10 ]
        do
            r.mapcalc < water.mapcalc
            d.rast water
            n='expr $n + 1'
        done
        g.copy rast=water,water.$i
        i = 'expr $i + 1'
    done
```

It is from http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/raster/mapcalc-algebra.pdf. I understand the syntax of the code since I am a programmer, but I cannot understand the line `r.mapcalc < water.mapcalc`. What does it mean? Sorry first time to use a shell script.

Answer (score 5):

It's input redirection -- just like you can redirect the output of a command into a file,:

```
command > outfile.txt
```

you can redirect the input *from* a file:

```
command < infile.txt
```

This is the same as:

```
cat infile.txt | command
```

Hopefully helpful!

Comment: I do not know if I understood it correctly. Does it mean that the output of the water.mapcalc is "redirected" to the command r.mapcalc? But, what does the command r.mapcalc compute? Isn't it that the r.mapcalc command needs additional parameters in order to work (map name and value)? I'm trying to make the Hydrologic Simulation in http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/raster/mapcalc-algebra.pdf work. Thanks

Comment: http://grass.fbk.eu/gdp/html_grass64/r.mapcalc.html should help. r.mapcalc is general purpose map algebra, and it will compute whatever the contents of the 'water.mapcalc' file tells it to compute.